# Angular add help file with the help text

Tags: angular, angular7

I want to have a separate file which should have all the help text in key value pair. So I can use them next to form labels on various components.

I have created app-config.ts for the same and used @Inject to inject it in various components.

app.config.ts

```
import { AppConfig } from './app-config';

export const APP_CONFIG = new InjectionToken<AppConfig>('app.config');

export const HELP_CONFIG: AppConfig = {
  help: {
    somekey: 'Lorem ipsum text',
    somekey: 'Lorem ipsum text',
    somekey: 'Lorem ipsum text',
    somekey: 'Lorem ipsum text',
    somekey: 'Lorem ipsum text',
  }
};
```

any.component.ts

```
  constructor(
    @Inject(APP_CONFIG) config: AppConfig
  ) {
    this.appConfig = config;
  }
```

any.template.html

```
<label [title]="appConfig.help.somekey"/>
```

I just wanna know if this is right approach. Or is there a better way to do this.

Comment: why dont you use a simple interface and use it whenever needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Typescript interfaces like:-

```
interface HelpInterface{
  somekey1: string,
  somekey2: string,
  somekey3: string
}

export const help: HelpInterface= {
  somekey1: 'Lorem ipsum text',
  somekey2: 'Lorem ipsum text',
  somekey3: 'Lorem ipsum text'
}
```

Now use this inside your components by importing them